# error: two or more data types in declaration of `serve'

Tags: c++, operating-system, extern

I get this error. The serve function just takes the urls created and put them inside  directory called downloads.

```
../threads/threadtest.cc:18: two or more data types in declaration of `serve'
```

I declare serve like this:

```
extern void serve(char *url);
```

why am I getting such an error? 
CODE:

```
#include "copyright.h"
#include "system.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "request.h"


extern void serve(char *url);

//GLOBAL VARIABLE LIST                                                                     
List *list;

void
ClientThread(int request)
{
  const int sz = 50;
  char url[sz];

  FILE *fp = fopen("url.txt", "r");
  if (!fp)
    printf("  Cannot open file url.txt!\n");
  else {
    int pos = 0;
    char c = getc(fp);
    while (c != EOF || pos == sz - 1) {
      if (c == '\n') {
        url[pos] = '\0';
        serve(url);
        pos = 0;

        //Store necessary information in a Request object for each request.                
        Request req(url, request, 1);

        Request *reqq = &req; //req points to the object                                   
        list->Append(reqq);
      }
      else {
        url[pos++] = c;
      }
      c = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says you are missing a ; after the declaration before the declaration of `serve`.

Comment: `extern void serve(char *url);` isn't an initialization; its a declaration. And it would probably help if you told us *in the question* which exact line was 18 as well as the surrounding code (a few lines before and after that declaration).